# How to get the edit and delete controller action to work

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I cannot get the edit and delete controller actions to work. I have almost identical code in another controller and that does not fail.

This is the edit form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/users">
  <input id="hidden" type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
  <div align="center">
....
    .....
  </div>
</form>
```

And relevant controller actions:

```
patch "/users/:id" do
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.name = params[:name]
    @user.email = params[:email]
    @user.password = params[:password]
    @user.save

    redirect to "/users/#{@user.id}"
  end

  #fix this delete request later
    delete '/users/:id' do
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @user.delete
      redirect '/users'
    end
```

I am getting the "Sinatra doesn't know this ditty" error message:

```
Try this:
# in application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController
  post '/users/' do
    "Hello World"
  end
end
```

I am not sure where the "post/users/" is coming from.

Comment: `"post/users/"` is simply an example, it's not suggesting that literal phrase should be in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form does not work since the action attribute is `/users` and your route is `/users/:id`.

Provided you have passed a user to the view you could do something like:

```
<form method="POST" action="/users/<%= @user.id %>">
```

However you're not actually handling the form submission in any decent way. When accepting user input you always want to check if the input is valid and that the record is actually saved. If you just assume everything is hunky-dory its going to blow up real fast.

If you are using ActiveRecord/Mongoid you would handle it like so:

```
patch "/users/:id" do
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update(params.slice(:name, :email, :password))
    redirect to "/users/#{@user.id}"
  else
    erb :edit # re-render the form
  end
end
```

Comment: <form method="POST" action="/users/<%= @user.id %>">
  <input id="hidden" type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
  give the error Try this:
# in application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController
  post '/users/31' do
    "Hello World"
  end
end

Comment: sorry for bad formatting, thanks for your help you've helped me before too I appreciate it.   its routing me to http://localhost:9393/users/31 and saying it doesnt exist i think.

Comment: and i agree that im not handing form submission correctly, im just trying to get the functionality to work, then handle the rest

Comment: I think its that your using `<input id="hidden" type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">` and not `value="PATCH"`. [Rack::MethodOverride](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/f9ad97fd69a6b3616d0a99e6bedcfb9de2f81f6c/lib/rack/method_override.rb#L5) is actually strict about the case.

Comment: That would explain why its being treated as a POST request instead of PATCH.

Comment: DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Apr/2020:10:02:29 -0500] "POST /users/31 HTTP/1.1" 404 541 0.0082
that is the output from the server, anything suspiscious there? Im getting the same error when i change the value, its still hitting the POST request.  i read over the code in the link, it looks like they upcase the request names

Comment: my config.ru was missing use Rack::MethodOverride. that was what was wrong. thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

So I fixed the issue. I was using this gem called Corneal to basically run a scaffold of the needed file structure, but it was missing the use Rack::MethodOverride link in config.ru. Thanks max for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Answers are not for summaries or thanks because SO isn't a message board or forum, it's more like an online reference book. If you intend this to be the selected answer then you should flesh it out into a real answer.